# Fill TextView on an Item for RecyclerView.LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a simple item. There is an icon on the left, and a text on the right. I do not want to fix the height or width because according to user's system font size, text could be larger.

There are two problems with my layout. Could someone tell me how I can solve the followings?

1. `TextView` does not fill the remaining item (I coloured it red to see if it filled the item) and the text on some items is truncated with an ellipse even though there are plenty of space on the item.
2. I do not know how to centre the image vertically (item height may vary according to text height which can very user's system settings).

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:focusable="true"
                 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
       >
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:id="@+id/ivIcon"/>
       <TextView
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:id="@+id/tvText"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:textSize="12pt"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

---Recycler View----
The height is 0dp because I want to fill the remaining height with this Recycler View.

```html
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

After applying "Nasz Njoka Sr."'s answer.
[image]

Comment: Post the child layout.

Comment: Can you just post the snap of the recyclerview, how its looking?

Comment: textVIew width set as match parent..

Comment: why text view is singleline android:singleLine="true" if you want it according to data remove it

Comment: I want the item to contain only a single line of text, so that each item will have the same height on a client. If the text is longer than the item width, I want it to be clipped. What I mean by "according to the settings" is the height of a single line can vary on different systems. Setting TextView's width as match_parent did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just align the imageview and the textview one left the other right and remove the weights instead use wrap_content

Example here

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center"/>
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: This solved that text gets clipped even though there is lots of space on the item, but still, the TextView does not fill the entire item. I can see the red area does not fill the whole line.

Comment: can you post an image for this issue?

Comment: I did. But please note that my purpose is not filling the item with red. The red is just for debugging purposes. I would like to learn how to fill an item.  Also, there seemed to be no gravity for ImageView and setting layout_gravity to start did not centre the image vertically. I used layout_gravity = "center_vertical" in the screenshot.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun make TextView width to match_parent

Comment: Setting it to match_parent seem to does not fill it, but only makes text clipped even there is a space.

Comment: It seems the problem was in the view inflation. In the onCreateViewHolder I had used "View.inflate()". I replaced it with LayoutInflator.from().inflate(). Now the TextView fills the line. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

because of SingleLine = true and weights you are applied to your code try bellow code once.

**Note:** Please consider for text size it's better to use sp(ScalePixels) instead of pt it will adjust automatically according to screen resolution and pixel density.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

`